# Referencing local variable within the same function

Tags: python-3.x, local-variables

I want to merge 2 DataFrames using a function.
The function creates DataFrame df1 when called with variable 'x=1', and then another, df2, when called with 'x != 1', based on an if-statement within the function - code snippet below for further clarity.

Upon reaching the "df3 = pd.concat" line, I get the error "**UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df1' referenced before assignment**".

I would like to understand how to achieve the result of concatenating df1 and df2 into df3.

```
def Concat(url, x):
    if x == 1:
        df1 = pd.read_json(url)
    else:
        df2 = pd.read_json(url)
        df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)


def main():
    Concat('*url*', 1)
    Concat('*url*', 2)
```

Comment: In the `else` block, you never define `df1`, so you get the `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: `both df1 and df2 are generated` that's where you're wrong. You have code for generating both but it will never run together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should tweak it a bit, to be:

```
def Concat(url, x):
    for i in x:
        if i == 1:
            df1 = pd.read_json(url)
        else:
            df2 = pd.read_json(url)
            df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)


def main():
    Concat('*url*', [1, 2])
```

Comment: Comments and answer make sense - I understand why I'm getting the error. Just to make sure I understand the Answer, does Concat run twice from main(), once with x=1 and once with x=2?

Comment: @FlybatRamirez Nope, now it doesn't, it runs once

Comment: Ah, I see, you pass a list - it didn't occur to me to do that. Quite elegant.

Comment: I've tested your code, however I'm still getting the same error = "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df1' referenced before assignment". It turns out df1 never gets created at all, so x ==1 is never True for some reason.

Comment: @FlybatRamirez Well that is probably an issue with your other code you didn't show us, Not my code...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236311/discussion-between-flybat-ramirez-and-u12-forward).